# No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient, pre-trained-model

I am currently trying to generate some adversarial images using tensorflow. I have now a working code to fool classification NN (inception v3) and I am trying to fool a detector. I choose Mask-RCNN. 
I suceed to retrieve the logits but I can't understand why I have an error :

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph
>   for ops that do not support gradients, between variables ["
>   tf.Variable 'Variable_33:0' shape=(299, 299, 3) dtype=float32_ref"]
>   and loss Tensor("softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_9/Reshape_2:0",
>   shape=(1,), dtype=float32).

Here is my entire code:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
image = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((299, 299, 3)))
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (299, 299, 3))
adv = image
assign_op = tf.assign(adv, x)
learning_rate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, ())
y_hat = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, ())
logits = tf.Variable(logits_[0])
labels = tf.one_hot(y_hat, 81)
loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=logits, labels=[labels])
optim_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss, var_list=adv)

epsilon = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, ())
projected = tf.clip_by_value(tf.clip_by_value(adv, x - epsilon, x + epsilon), 0, 1)
with tf.control_dependencies([projected]):
   project_step = tf.assign(adv, projected)

demo_epsilon = 2.0/255.0 # a really small perturbation
demo_lr = 1e-1
demo_target = 2

sess.run(assign_op, feed_dict={x: images[0]})

for i in range(100):
   _, loss_value = sess.run([optim_step, loss], feed_dict={learning_rate: demo_lr, y_hat: demo_target})
   assign_ope = logits.assign(fast_rcnn_1(img))
   sess.run(assign_ope)
   sess.run(project_step, feed_dict={x: img, epsilon: demo_epsilon})
   if (i+1) % 10 == 0:
       print('step %d, loss=%g' % (i+1, loss_value))

adversarial = adv.eval()
```

and I retrieve the logits with :

```
def fast_rcnn_1(image):

molded_image, window, scale, padding, crop = resize_image(
    image,
    min_dim=IMAGE_MIN_DIM,
    min_scale=IMAGE_MIN_SCALE,
    max_dim=IMAGE_MAX_DIM,
    mode=IMAGE_RESIZE_MODE)
molded_image = mold_image(molded_image)

image_meta = compose_image_meta(
    0, image.shape, molded_image.shape, window, scale,
    np.zeros([NUM_CLASSES], dtype=np.int32))


image_shape = molded_image.shape
anchors = model.get_anchors(image_shape)
anchors = np.broadcast_to(anchors, (1,) + anchors.shape)


logit = model2.predict([molded_image[None,...], image_meta[None,...], anchors], verbose=1)[0][0]
prob = softmax(logit)

return logit
```

model2 is obtained by cutting mask rcnn model at layer "mrcnn_class_logits":

```
model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="inference", model_dir=MODEL_DIR, config=config)
model.load_weights(COCO_MODEL_PATH, by_name=True)
layer_name = 'mrcnn_class_logits'
model2= Model(inputs=model.keras_model.input, outputs=model.keras_model.get_layer(layer_name).output)
```

My tensorflow version is 1.9.0.
I have ever tried to change the shape of logits and labels but the problem seems to come from another mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error comes from this line:

`model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="inference", model_dir=MODEL_DIR, config=config)`

This will create the graph for MaskRCNN in inference mode which improve inference performances by removing some operations, puts variables trainable to False and stop gradient propagation.

Just change the "mode" attribute to training and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, but in fact I don't want to update the parameters of the model. The idea is to change a bit the input image in order to become adversarial. That's why I give to the GradientDescentOptimizer my adversarial image. I was thinking that the mistake come to the fact that my logits are not retrieve in a good way. I tried to change my code to update them before each call to sess.run() but I didn't suceed.

Comment: 'I don't want to update the parameters of the model'
Since you provide a var_list to the optimizer, only the variables in this list will be updated which means that only the image tensor will be modified even if you are in 'training' mode.

Comment: I was thinking about your solution but I just realized that in the original code of mask rcnn https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/mrcnn/model.py, you can't call the detect function which is usefull to get the logits in the training mode. The function is only available in 'inference' mode dure to this assertion :  assert self.mode == "inference" line 2500